# java GUI actionperformed and ButtonListener

Tags: java

I am attempting to make a GUI in Java that takes information entered in three text fields and displays the information (first name, last name, and sport) of an athlete in a text area after pressing a button. I was able to create the JFrame with all the Jlabels, Jtextfields, JtextArea, and Jbutton, but I am unable to figure out how to take the entered text and put it into the proper athlete format as well as adding some kind of dialog box above that submits 'athlete added' if all textfields are filled, and 'please fill all categories' if the textfields were not all filled. I will post the code I have below, any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the Setup class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Setup extends JApplet
 {

   private int APPLET_WIDTH = 500, APPLET_HEIGHT = 400;

   private JTabbedPane tPane;
   private CreatePanel createPanel;
   private CountPanel countPanel;
   private Vector athleteList;

   //The method init initializes the Applet with a Pane with two tabs
   public void init()
    {
     //list of athletes to be used in every panel
    athleteList = new Vector();

     //register panel uses the list of athletes
     countPanel = new CountPanel(athleteList);

     createPanel = new CreatePanel(athleteList, countPanel);

     //create a tabbed pane with two tabs
     tPane = new JTabbedPane();
     tPane.addTab("Athlete Creation", createPanel);
     tPane.addTab("Medal Count", countPanel);

     getContentPane().add(tPane);
     setSize (APPLET_WIDTH, APPLET_HEIGHT); //set Applet size
    }
}
```

Here is the athlete class:

```
public class Athlete
 {
   private String firstName, lastName;
   private String sport;
   private int gold, silver, bronze;

   //Constructor to initialize all member variables
   public Athlete()
    {
      firstName = "?";
      lastName = "?";
      sport = "?";
      gold = 0;
      silver = 0;
      bronze = 0;
    }

   //Accessor methods
   public String getFirstName()
    {
      return firstName;
    }

   public String getLastName()
    {
      return lastName;
    }

   public String getSport()
    {
      return sport;
    }

   //Mutator methods
   public void setFirstName(String first)
    {
     firstName = first;
    }

   public void setLastName(String last)
    {
     lastName = last;
    }

   public void setSport(String someSport)
    {
     sport = someSport;
    }

   //Methods to increase the count of medals
   public void increaseGold()
    {
     gold++;
    }

   public void increaseSilver()
    {
     silver++;
    }

   public void increaseBronze()
    {
     bronze++;
    }

   //toString() method returns a string containg information of an athlete
   public String toString()
    {
      String result = "Name:\t" + lastName + "," + firstName + "\n"
                    + "Sport:\t" + sport + "\n"
                    + "Medal Count:\n" 
                    + "Gold: " + gold + "\n"
                    + "Silver: " + silver + "\n"
                    + "Bronze: " + bronze + "\n\n";
      return result;
     }
  }
```

And here is what I've been experimenting with in the Athlete Creation Panel:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CreatePanel extends JPanel
 {
   private Vector athleteList;
   private CountPanel cPanel;
   private int count; 
   private JTextField textField;
   private JTextField textField_1;
   private JTextField textField_2;

 //Constructor initializes components and organize them using certain layouts
 public CreatePanel(Vector athleteList, CountPanel cPanel)
  {
    count = 0;  

    this.setAthleteList(athleteList);
    this.cPanel = cPanel;
    setLayout(null); 

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("No Athlete");
    textArea.setBounds(252, 16, 183, 268);
    add(textArea);

    JLabel lblFirstName = new JLabel("First Name");
    lblFirstName.setBounds(15, 100, 89, 20);
    add(lblFirstName);

    JLabel lblLastName = new JLabel("Last Name");
    lblLastName.setBounds(15, 135, 89, 20);
    add(lblLastName);

    JLabel lblSport = new JLabel("Sport");
    lblSport.setBounds(15, 170, 69, 20);
    add(lblSport);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(120, 100, 125, 25);
    add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setBounds(120, 135, 125, 25);
    add(textField_1);
    textField_1.setColumns(10);

    textField_2 = new JTextField();
    textField_2.setBounds(120, 170, 125, 25);
    add(textField_2);
    textField_2.setColumns(10);

    JButton button1 = new JButton("Create an Athlete");
    button1.addActionListener(new ButtonListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
    button1.setBounds(48, 206, 155, 29);
    add(button1);

  }

 //ButtonListener is a listener class that listens to
 //see if the button "Create an Athlete" is pushed.
 //When the event occurs, it adds an athlete using the information
 //entered by a user.
 //It also performs error checking.
 private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
  {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {

        //TO BE COMPLETED
       //p1 = ((Object) event).getAthlete(); 

       textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "/n"
               + textField.getText()
               + textField_1.getText()
               + textField_2.getText()); 

       count++; 
       athleteList.setSize(count);

       String firsttf = textField.getText();
       String lasttf = textField_1.getText();
       String sporttf = textField_2.getText();

       //Athlete.setFirstName(firsttf); 

       JDialog success = new JDialog(success, "athlete added.");
       success.setBounds(15, 50, 80, 20);

       JDialog fail = new JDialog(fail, "Please enter all fields.");
       fail.setBounds(15, 50, 100, 20); 

       success.setVisible(false);
       fail.setVisible(false);

       if (firsttf.length() >= 1 && lasttf.length() >= 1 && sporttf.length() >= 1){
           success.setVisible(true);
           //x = new Athlete(firsttf, lasttf, sporttf); 
       }

       else if (firsttf.length() < 1 || lasttf.length() < 1 || sporttf.length() < 1){
           fail.setVisible(true);
       }



    } //end of actionPerformed method
 } //end of ButtonListener class

private void setAthleteList(Vector athleteList2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
} //end of CreatePanel class
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
button1.addActionListener(new ButtonListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
```

To this:

```
button1.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
```

The way you have coded currently the actionPerformed(...) method is overriding the method in ButtonListener.